# Is FileSystemObject CopyFile a blocking call?

Tags: vbscript

I'm using FileSytemObject CopyFile to copy a text file to a shared folder. Is this method a blocking call? In other words, will it halt the script? I've looked in the MSDN and other places but can't seem to find any resources that state this.

Right now, my script copies a file from a local folder to a shared folder. The next line checks to see if it exists and if it does, then it deletes the local copy.

```
    fso.CopyFile "C:\myText.txt", "\\SharedFolder\myText.txt"
    If (fso.FileExists("\\SharedFolder\myText.txt")) Then
        fso.DeleteFile "C:\myText.txt"
    End If
```

Is the fso.CopyFile a blocking call?

Comment: What happens when you run the script, does it finish copying `myText.txt` then delete the local file? I think by it's very nature it has to be synchronous. I can only assume it's not working as you expected if you are asking the question in the first place though. If the `CopyFile` operation fails it will throw an error. See [Copying a File](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee198744.aspx).

Comment: @Lankymart It works fine. I just wanted to verify that it is a blocking call. If it isn't then there could be scenarios where I would have issues.

Comment: Most calls if not all of them in VBScript are synchronous calls, it's the nature of VBScript. If it wasn't you would need callbacks to handle the asynchronous nature of the calls.

Comment: Yes, virtually everything is blocking. Do you have an actual problem? Does the code not work for you?

Comment: The only thing I've run into that isn't synchronous is calling `Shell` which just chucks the call over to `shell` and continue on its merry way.

Comment: @JNevill Perhaps that was what I had read then. I read somewhere that the Folder.CopyHere method is Async. That was why I was concerned with the CopyFile method being asynchronous. But now I see that the Folder.CopyHere is part of the shell which is Async.

Comment: I believe that `folder.copyhere` is a method of `shell` so I would expect it to be async. As I was thinking about this, the `internetexplorer.navigate` is async too, so I guess it's reasonable to be concerned. My bet is still that `fso` stuff are synchronous.